# How to add custom number to shape in draw io

Tags: drawing, draw, draw.io

Does anyone know how to add below number(10) in [draw io](https://app.diagrams.net/)?  thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use number plugin as described here: https://www.diagrams.net/doc/faq/number-plugin

If this doesn't suit your needs, just add circle with the number, click Ctrl+e on the circle, add "" resizeWidth=0;resizeHeight=0;"
and then group shapes. This is not a perfect solution but it might help.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 options.

###### Option 1: Use the existing shapes (1) to (9)

Just search for "number" and you'll get 9 prepared shapes which you can drag-and-drop.
[image]

###### Option 2: Create the shape yourself

Just use a circle, double-click on it and enter your number. You'll need to make the font size bigger and the circle a bit smaller for it to look nice. Then, you can copy-paste that shape to create further numbers.
[image]

###### Option 3: Use the enumeration feature

Enable the `Enumerate` property and set the value for `Enumerate value`.
[image]

It'll look like this.
[image]

Here is a blog post: https://www.diagrams.net/blog/number-shapes

###### Option 4: Use the plugin

Here is a blog post: https://www.diagrams.net/doc/faq/number-plugin

This option seems obsolete since the feature is built in to Draw.io. See option 3 above.